# How to get VSCode Liveshare extension working when running inside VSCode Remote Dev Container

Tags: vscode-remote, vscode-liveshare

When installing the LiveShare extension in a `devContainer` instance I get an error.

For example using: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-try-go/ and then adding the extension to the `devcontainer.json` file

```
    "extensions": [
        "ms-vscode.go",
        "ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-pack"
    ]
```

When I attempt to start a liveshare I see:

> Agent terminated with exit code: 0 and signal null: FailFast: Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String) at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode() at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor() at System.Globalization.CultureData.CreateCultureWithInvariantData() at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_Invariant() at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor() at System.StringComparer..cctor() at System.AppDomain.InitializeCompatibilityFlags() at System.AppDomain.Setup(System.Object)Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out that this requires the docker images to install `icu` tools and then things function as expected.

For the `golang` image I added:

```
RUN apt update && apt install icu-devtools -y
```

The rebuild the container and things worked nicely.

One thing to note is that you need to use the alternative sign in flow using a code to signin

[image]